# WC session custom data is cleared after user login in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have a code (big thanks to LoicTheAztec) I use for passing variables from the url to the woocommerce session and it works great for orders where the visitor does not need to log in (guest checkout)

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'set_custom_variables_wc_session' );
function set_custom_variables_wc_session(){
    $src   = isset( $_GET['src'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['src'] ) : "";
    $subid = isset( $_GET['subid'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['subid'] ) : "";
    
    WC()->session->set('custom_data',['src' => $src, 'subid'=> $subid]);
}
```

I did a `print_r` on the checkout page, and they show, and are saving no problem for guest checkouts (not subscriptions that require logins):

```
Array
(
    [src] => test100
    [subid] => 98754
)
```

But, if the product is a subscription and the user already has an account, WooCommerce asks the user to login, and when they use the login form on the checkout page all these variables get cleared from the session.

```
Array
(
    [src] => 
    [subid] => 

)
```

In other words, right after the user logs in on the checkout page, they end up on the same page, but all the session `custom_data` variables are gone.

I looked around but couldn't find any info on somehow saving this data, even if the user logs in, so it's not lost.

How do I get the current session `custom_data` to stay in place even if the returning user logs in on the checkout form?

I tried to look for a solution for saving `custom_data`, but couldn't find.

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing things in the right way, with your code on a reload the WC Session data array values are cleared. Instead, use the following:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'set_custom_variables_wc_session' );
function set_custom_variables_wc_session(){
    if( isset($_GET['src']) && ! empty($_GET['src']) && isset($_GET['subid']) && ! empty($_GET['subid']) ) {
        $custom_data = ['src' => esc_attr($_GET['src']), 'subid'=> esc_attr($_GET['subid'])];
        WC()->session->set('custom_data', $custom_data); 
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

This time, the WC Session data will persist.

---

**Addition:** WC Session and "guest" users

Here below is even a better way early enabling WC Session for" guest" users. Normally for guests users, WC Session is started on the first add to cart.

The following code will early enable WC Session for guests, allowing to store custom data in WC Session in all cases:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'set_custom_variables_wc_session' );
function set_custom_variables_wc_session(){ 
    // Not on backend and only for guests
    if ( ! ( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() ) ) {
        // Early enable WC Session for guest users
        if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
            WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true ); 
        }
    }
    // Store Url variable(s) in WC Session custom variable(s)
    if( isset($_GET['src']) && ! empty($_GET['src']) && isset($_GET['subid']) && ! empty($_GET['subid']) ) {
        $custom_data = ['src' => esc_attr($_GET['src']), 'subid'=> esc_attr($_GET['subid'])];
        WC()->session->set('custom_data', $custom_data); 
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.